# Display language in entity reference field

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, entities

I am running a multilanguage website and I have some content types using entity references. Now, the problem is that when I am adding content, if I have two content with the same name but different languages (a product name for instance), I have no way to know which one I am choosing in the entity reference field. 
So I want to be able to display language in the entity reference select box. Something like this :

```
Lorem Ipsum (EN)
Lorem Ipsum (IT)
...
```

Is there any module I can use for that or some hooks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with views. Views allows you to add a "Reference" display. There you can choose how your title or your reference entry should look like. The view can then be chosen from the settings of the node reference field.