# multilingual while adding content

Tags: 7, nodes, i18n-l10n

I have enabled the i18n module and created a taxonomy vocabulary with translated terms. In addition I have created a CT (content type) in which I've added a term reference field of this taxonomy vocabulary.

Is there a way while I'm authoring a new content of this CT to have to choose only among the user's current language terms? At this point I'm seeing a list of 10x3 (30) terms 'cause I got 3 languages, and that's a bit of chaos for the authors.

Thanks in advanced, I hope I've been clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a node reference view. Check this answer for more information:
[Display language in entity reference field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62275/display-language-in-entity-reference-field/62276#62276)

You can either limit your entries in the reference field or show the language in every entry.

Comment: Great, had no clue that views have "reference" display, thanks a lot. Does this require entity reference module?

Comment: Yes i think so ...

Comment: While I'm authoring a new node, I've got the language dropdown menu option, is it possible the terms to be filtered based on this field instead of current user's language? I think this would be much more handy