# How to limit Entity Reference to only allow referencing of nodes with the same (or undefined) language?

Tags: views, entities, i18n-l10n

I know I can simply [add language to displayed title](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62275/display-language-in-entity-reference-field/62276#62276) of a node in Entity Reference field based on views. What I failed to discover is how to limit possible values to only show and allow matching ones.

- When current node is language independent, all nodes should be listed as possible in reference field.
- When node has language defined, only nodes of the same language, or undefined language, should be available.

I don't really mind wrong selection to be saved in database if language of node will be changed, as it shouldn't happen often enough to be a problem. I simply don't want "wrong" nodes on the list of available reference choices. On-save validation would be nice, but isn't a must-have.

I tried to use view to populate entityreference field's dropdown on node edit form:

[image: Screenshot of field settings]

My big block is how to access a language of a current node in view that provides list of available entities. I can't find a way other than to guess using current UI language, but that may be wrong for edits and usually is wrong on new node creation. Ideally, the entity reference field should repopulate via AJAX according to the language selected in the node edit from.

For the sake of future visitors I would appreciate complete answer. Of course answer not based on views will be appreciated, too.

Comment: Since I have few knowledge on Entity Ref, It is difficult to understand the question, So are you looking something similar to this module https://drupal.org/project/cer

Comment: I don't know may be this could be the answer https://drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit  . You can also integrate with the entity reference fields

Comment: @Bala Reference field option limit might be an answer. Certainly what it claims to do would be enough. If you can check if it and post as an answer, would be nice. I'll test it when I'll find a bit of time, of course, but I cannot reward bounty on comments :P

Comment: Still searching for you have look https://drupal.org/project/entityreference_dynamicselect_widget

Comment: @Bala - no use unless I want to repeat language next to reference dropdown. Maybe could be used as a codebase for custom solution, but that's all. Now experimenting with computed fields (@language) and reference option limit, but field can be computed on read and on save it seems... not live on edit form.

Comment: I think i found one solution for you, see the another answer

Comment: could you tell what do you use for multilanguage system? did you succeed to define the language of your node?

Answer (score 4):

[Reference field option limit](https://drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit) module allows reference fields of several types to have their widgets' available options limited by the values of other fields in the current entity.

> It currently supports taxonomy term and [entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) fields.

Comment: Docs looks good. To bad I cannot make it work. [Issue 2082217](https://drupal.org/node/2082217) might or might not be the reason. We'll see. Will test more. Anyway, it seems to be a nice code to start with.

Comment: Sadly, language is not exposed as a field... Testing continues ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest some "concepts" of solution with Views.

I didn't understood if you succeed to define target node language. (if no, write a comment, I'll update the answer).

**Step1.** You are able to pass arguments to the view that filters entityreference field. Then it's possible to add your language to the field views args programmatically in `$field['settings']['handler_settings']['view']['args'];`.

**Step2.** You can create custom contextual filter programmatically. Filter will pass the language id. This contextual will change View language using agrument value. you can change language in query alter - `query()` method of your child class of `views_handler_argument`.

Then just `dpm($this)` in the `query()` method and change language value to your argument.

Comment: Not bad concepts, but it seems basically you are telling me to rebuild [Reference field option limit](http://drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit) Bala [suggested](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/84680/16495), only with language instead of fields :)

Comment: Yes, you have now solution for both fields and language :)  Unfortunately I'm not common with "Reference field option limit". I suggested custom coding

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Translated Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/translated_entityreference) module.

Another option is to create your custom view to render your Entity Reference field selectable options. Just:

1. Create a new view
2. Add a new Entity Reference View Widget
3. Add a filter for your content type
4. Add a new contextual filter for field "Language"
5. Select "Provide default value" + "PHP code" (maybe you will need
   "Views PHP" module for this)
6. Enter this code on "PHP contextual filter code" textarea:

   global $language;
   $lang = $language->language;

   $node = menu_get_object();
   if (!empty($node)) {
     $lang = $node->language;
   }
   return $lang;
7. Edit your Entity Reference field and select your new custom view as
   entity selection mode

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing.

The closest I got was by using the current user's language. 
The current user's language will be determined by what you select in `/admin/config/regional/language/configure`.

- add relationship "Entity translation: translations"
- add filter "Entity translation: Language (=Current user's language)"

Also, this link cleared the field_title issue for me: https://drupal.org/node/1327012.

So, for example, going to `/en/node/add` will populate the entity view with the referenced entities in English.
But, if the user changes the language on the edit form the view will remain the same.

This solution would suffice if the referenced entities were the same in all languages and simply translated (like the "localize terms" functionality that that core taxonomy translation provides).

The only other 'quick and dirty' way I can think of is editing the output of the title field in views and adding a css class according to the language. Then writing some jquery that shows/hides the entities by mapping the class of the entity in the view to the language selection field.

****Ideally, the entity view should repopulate via ajax according to the language selected in the node edit from.****

If anybody has any ideas please let us know.

Thanks

Comment: It does not actually provide an answer, only something colse + comments. If you don't mind maybe we should integrate these comments into my question? On the other hand, you would not get reputation from that question... I will not flag it or anything

Comment: That's why I said that "I'm looking for the same thing". I just thought that my comments might be helpful to you and others who might try to answer. 

Feel free to integrate my comments into your question. I'm not expecting any points or anything.

Answer (score 0):

[Field reference](https://drupal.org/project/field_reference)

> Depending on configuration, authors can pick fields from the same
>   node/entity, from other nodes/entities, from specific revisions, from
>   specific languages, or even a specific delta value within the field.
>   Fields can be displayed using either the 'full' or 'teaser' mode from
>   their original node/entity.

Comment: Quick test seems to indicate that you need to hard-configure language and it will not change live. I'll be glad if you can prove me wrong. Last but not least, I need to reference entities, not their fields. But that's a minor problem I guess.